# extending Exception to allow for auto appending class name on exception message

Tags: php, exception-handling

Got this idea from the php.net website on extending exceptions. The main thing I wanted with this was to have the exception name auto imprinted on the exception message, so I wouldn't have to write it in each message. So far its working, just wondering if this is efficient or not?

Thanks

```
class DataException extends Exception 
{
   protected $solved;
   protected $howSolved;

   public function __construct($message, $solved = false, $howSolved = null, 
                               $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) 
   {
      $this->solved = $solved;
      $this->howSolved = $howSolved;

      // make sure everything is assigned properly
      parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
   }

   public function setSolved($isSolved)
   {
      $this->solved = $isSolved;
   }

   public function setHowSolved($howSolved)
   {
      $this->howSolved = $howSolved;
   }

}

class GeoCoordinateOutOfBoundsException extends DataException 
{
   public function __construct($message, $solved = false, $howSolved = null, 
                               $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) 
   {
      $message = get_class($this) . "::" . $message;

      // make sure everything is assigned properly
      parent::__construct($message, $solved, $howSolved, $code, $previous);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to change arguments order in ctor for better compatibility with parent calss.
`public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null, $solved = false, $howSolved = null)`
And getters for `$soved` and `$howSolved` seems to be missing.

Why not to use magic constant `__CLASS__` instead of `get_class($this)`, which can be written as `get_class()` in your case.

Comment: yeah forgot the getters for `DataException` and also changed the argument order you describe [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php), good idea I think. 

As for the magic methods, I know about them, used some for serialization, `__sleep()` and `__wake()` but I find some
of those magic methods dont provide the verbosity I like to see with explicitly named methods.. self documenting

Also I dont think adding functionality through inheritance is going against the core design priciples of OOP.. but thats another topic.

Comment: I meant magic constant, not method. There are some "pre-defined" constants, like `__CLASS__`, `__METHOD__`, `__FUNCTION__` (RTFM). `__CLASS__` produces same results as `get_class($this)` (I do not want to open discussion that may lead to dark moments of namespaces, inheritance, traits - your case is simple). And `get_class($this)` may be reduced to `get_class()` for it has default argument.

Answer (score 2):

Changing an inherited method signature isn't a good idea. It means how you call a method changes depending on what exact class you're calling.

[Exception::__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) has only 3 arguments, but the first of which can be anything. As such you could do:

```
class DataException extends Exception 
{
   protected $solved;
   protected $howSolved;

   public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {
    $solved = $howSolved = false;
    if (is_array($message))  {
        $solved = $message['solved']; // message is an array
        ...
        $message = $message['message']; // and now it's a string to be used/compatible with the parent
    }
```

Which would work whether $message was a string or an array - and without changing the method signature.

Why do you have setters for properties on a exception? Sounds like you're using exceptions for something they aren't designed.